# Plotly graph isn't showing up

Tags: python, plotly

Error:
*{'text/html': '        \n        window.PlotlyConfig = {MathJaxConfig: 'local'};\n        if (window.MathJax) {MathJax.Hub.Config({SVG: {font: "STIX-Web"}});}\n        if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {\n        require.undef("plotly");\n        requirejs.config({\n            paths: {\n                'plotly': ['https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min']\n            }\n        });\n        require(['plotly'], function(Plotly) {\n            window._Plotly = Plotly;\n        });\n        }\n        \n        '}*

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import cufflinks as cf
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['A','B','C'],'Values':[32,43,50]})

df.iplot()

plt.show()
```

I'm assuming that it's because I'm using the Windows Console, and plotly can't show/run in the Windows Command Prompt. If that's the issue, then how can I get it to show in the prompt?

Comment: The code is working as expected in my system

Comment: Oops, try now..

Comment: Yes, it's working fine

Comment: Odd... It's not displaying anything for me. Are you using the Windows Console? I think it might be since I'm using `plt.show()`

Comment: I'm using jupyter notebook